# Types of WCF Service (ajax, data service, standard service etc)

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010

Can anyone point me in the direction of a comparison of the "standard" types of WCF Service as seen in VS2010 "Add New Item"?

e.g.
WCF Service
AJAX-enabled WCF Service
WCF Data Service

What each one is targetted for/when you would use it?
Advantages/disadvantages etc?
Can you add multiple endpoints and re-use the same service for combinations/all three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907578.aspx

Rob

Comment: I was unable to tell what the difference between the plain vanilla [WCF Service] was compared to [WCF Data Service] or [AJAX-enabled WCF Service].